# loop through all environmental variables and take actions depending on prefix

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I am trying to make a batch script where I can get all environmental variables based on a specified prefix or suffix and then and then do an update on said value.

I know the actual update would be a `SETX` command but im having trouble getting the list of variables I need.  I tried the `SET` command but it lists everything. Is there a way to iterate through the `SET` results?   Or otherwise do partial matches and loop through all the finds?

Comment: **Prefix**: read `set /?`; then you know that e.g. `set PRO` would display all variables that begin with the (case insensitive) string `PRO`. **Iterate through the `SET` results**: read [`FOR /F` loop command against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is there a way to iterate through the `SET` results?

You can use `for /f` to loop through the results.

**DisplayEnv.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
setlocal
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in ('set') do (
  echo Variable: %%a, Value: %%b
  )
endlocal
```

**Example output:**

```
F:\test>DisplayEnv.cmd
Variable: ALLUSERSPROFILE, Value: C:\ProgramData
Variable: APPDATA, Value: C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Roaming
Variable: asl.log, Value: Destination
Variable: CommonProgramFiles, Value: C:\Program Files\Common Files
Variable: CommonProgramFiles(x86), Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
Variable: CommonProgramW6432, Value: C:\Program Files\Common Files
Variable: COMPUTERNAME, Value: HAL
Variable: ComSpec, Value: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
Variable: configsetroot, Value: C:\Windows\ConfigSetRoot
Variable: DOCS, Value: C:\Users\DavidPostill\Documents
Variable: FP_NO_HOST_CHECK, Value: NO
Variable: HOMEDRIVE, Value: C:
Variable: HOMEPATH, Value: \Users\DavidPostill
Variable: LOCALAPPDATA, Value: C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Local
Variable: LOGONSERVER, Value: \\HAL
Variable: NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS, Value: 4
Variable: OS, Value: Windows_NT
Variable: Path, Value: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apps\WSCC\Sysinternals Suite;C:\apps\WSCC\NirSoft Utilities
Variable: PATHEXT, Value: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
Variable: PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE, Value: AMD64
Variable: PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER, Value: Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
Variable: PROCESSOR_LEVEL, Value: 6
Variable: PROCESSOR_REVISION, Value: 2a07
Variable: ProgramData, Value: C:\ProgramData
Variable: ProgramFiles, Value: C:\Program Files
Variable: ProgramFiles(x86), Value: C:\Program Files (x86)
Variable: ProgramW6432, Value: C:\Program Files
Variable: PROMPT, Value: $P$G
Variable: PSModulePath, Value: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
Variable: PUBLIC, Value: C:\Users\Public
Variable: RANDFILE, Value: C:\apps\NTP\etc\.rnd
Variable: SESSIONNAME, Value: Console
Variable: SystemDrive, Value: C:
Variable: SystemRoot, Value: C:\Windows
Variable: TEMP, Value: c:\temp
Variable: TMP, Value: c:\temp
Variable: USERDOMAIN, Value: Hal
Variable: USERNAME, Value: DavidPostill
Variable: USERPROFILE, Value: C:\Users\DavidPostill
Variable: windir, Value: C:\Windows
Variable: windows_tracing_flags, Value: 3
Variable: windows_tracing_logfile, Value: C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log
```

---

#### Can I do partial matches on the results?

The above batch file can be enhanced using `findstr` to filter the for loop.

**FindInEnv.cmd:**

```
@echo off 
setlocal
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in ('set ^| findstr /i / "%1"') do (
  echo Variable: %%a, Value: %%b
  )
endlocal
```

Usage:

- Pass the string to match as a parameter to `FindInEnv`
- Remove `/i` perform a case sensitive search.
- `findstr` support for regular expressions is limited and non-standard.
- See [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) for details on exactly is supported.

**Example output:**

```
F:\test>FindInEnv.cmd Program*
Variable: ALLUSERSPROFILE, Value: C:\ProgramData
Variable: CommonProgramFiles, Value: C:\Program Files\Common Files
Variable: CommonProgramFiles(x86), Value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
Variable: CommonProgramW6432, Value: C:\Program Files\Common Files
Variable: ProgramData, Value: C:\ProgramData
Variable: ProgramFiles, Value: C:\Program Files
Variable: ProgramFiles(x86), Value: C:\Program Files (x86)
Variable: ProgramW6432, Value: C:\Program Files
Variable: PSModulePath, Value: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.